# Draw text on BitmapData in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, bitmapdata

Well, the problem may be a simple one but I can't figure it out. I have an image loaded into BitmapData. now I want to take text from a textinput and put it on the BitmapData. Basically it's drawing a text on the BitmapData and get the result as another BitmapData that will consist of the original BitmapData with the text drawn over it on a specified position. What's the best way to achieve this in flex?

Comment: Are you trying to watermark/modify the original image itself or just display some text on top of the image in your application?

Comment: Not exactly watermark. I just want to add the text over the BitmapData and save it as a completely new image (with both the image and the text). So yeah, modify the original image by adding text on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To put the text inside a bitmap you can do:

```
var channelName:TextField = new TextField();
channelName.textColor=0x000000;
channelName.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.NORMAL;
channelName.alpha=1.0;
var txtFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat("SansSerif",14,0x000000,true);
channelName.setTextFormat(txtFormat);

var bitmapdata:BitmapData = new BitmapData(
         channelName.width, channelName.height, true, 0x000000);
bitmapdata.draw(channelName);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. However, whatever I do the text appears at the top left corner of the Bitamp image (0,0), how can I make it appear wherever I want on the Bitmapdata Image?

Comment: You can use a matrix and the translate method : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't draw over bitmapdata per say, but you could compose it from the data.  Since you have BitmapData, it's easy enough to change it to a bitmap (`var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);`) and then add it as source for an image.

Now that you have an actual image on the stage, you can now add text above that using what you like (text, label, textarea, etc) and then you can do a `Bitmap.draw` over the dimensions of the image to get the pixel information back into a BitmapData (under Bitmap.bitmapData).

Comment: Sounds good. However,I may have a problem with regards to my requirement with this approach (I am not sure though). The BitmapData is of large dimension and is scaled down when I load it into an image, to fit the image dimension. If I convert this Bitmap to BitmapData and save will it not be of the dimension of the Image (that is, scaled down image), How can I keep the original dimension in this case?

Comment: Have you try adding the image control but not set the width and height of the control?

Comment: Yes. But the problem here is the application requirement of loading different images at runtime. So some of the image may be of higher resolution that needs to be scaled down to fit the image area, but while saving it should be saved in the original dimension. If I don't set the width/height of the image, a higher dimension image runs out of display area, if I am able to explain it correctly. What workaround I can use?

Comment: How about using the ImageSnapshot to save the component.